# How to remove the gap between \underline and overline for the Roman Numbers shown in the below table without changing its font?

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, roman-numerals, xtable

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\scalebox{2}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Standard & University & Board & Class\\
\hline
$\overline{\underline{XII}}^{th}$ & ABC & IIP & $\overline{\underline{II}}^{nd}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Choose a short title, and write your question before your code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use the `romanbar` package to write Roman numbers with bars above and below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{romanbar}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Standard & University & Board & Class\\
\hline
\Romanbar{12}\textsuperscript{th} & ABC & IIP & \Romanbar{2}\textsuperscript{nd}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I try to reduce the size of the table then this Romanbar font looks bold. Is there any way to make it less darker? since it looks very different from the rest other text.

Comment: @Vishakha can't reproduce this problem. Even if I scale the table down all the way to tiny, the Roman numerals looks fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWh8z.png